# How to exit a shell script without closing the ssh/telnet session in which it is running

Tags: shell, unix, error-handling, solaris, ksh

I am trying to make a  KornShell (ksh) script compile all the Java files in a folder.

This script is called by Apache Ant, and hence I need to return an error code, so that it will know when to fail.

```
function check_if_error
{
    if [ $1 != 0 ]
    then 
        echo "Unable to compile java module"
        echo "Error code $1"
        echo "Reason: $2 module"
        java_fail=1
        exit 1
    fi
}


echo "Compiling the java files..."
javac com/cmsi/eValuate/ScriptProcessor/*.java
check_if_error $? "ScriptProcessor"
```

I have forced a compilation error in one of the Java files, so when it hits the `exit 1` part of the function, it kills the telnet session with which I am logged into the box and running this script.

I tried `return`, but `return` does not kill the shell script, it just keeps running through.

I tried `kill -1 $$`, but this closed the terminal session as well.

I am using Solaris 5 OS.

Comment: what telnet session? you need to show that too

Comment: The session in which I am running the shell script.

Comment: I meant to say terminal session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
echo compiling...
if ! javac com/cmsi/eValuate/ScriptProcessor/*.java
then
    echo "compilation errors"
    return 1
fi
```

I'm not familiar with ant, but it sounds like it's executing (sourcing) your code in your current shell instead of spawning a subshell which can exit successfully.

Comment: Your note gave me an idea, where in I called this script from another, and it exited both scripts on error.